# How do you run multiple PHP versions on the same site (and source files) in IIS7?

Tags: php, iis

I'd like to have a simple way to switch PHP versions to test the same application.

E.g. I would like to use xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:100 for PHP4 and I would like to use xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:200 for PHP5

But both use the same source files.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Using vhosts, this is possible. read this article http://gggeek.altervista.org/2007/07/21/running-multiple-php-versions-on-a-single-apache-install/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You'll need to create two websites within IIS that point to the same physical path (your PHP source files), and also ensure that the site bindings for each site use a different port, as you've suggested, port 100 and 200.

You'll then need to configure the handler mappings for each site, I recommend you follow these instructions to do that: [Run Multiple Versions of PHP on IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/run-multiple-versions-of-php-on-iis)